# Swift - Join button to strings

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a UITextView that is populated from a database query.

```
if myDatabase.open(){

            var arrayData:[String] = []

            let query_lab_test = "SELECT lab_test FROM lab_test ORDER BY lab_test ASC"

            let results_lab_test:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(query_lab_test, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results_lab_test?.next() == true {

                if let resultString = results_lab_test?.stringForColumn("lab_test"){

                    arrayData.append(resultString)

                }
            }

            let multiLineString = arrayData.joinWithSeparator("\n")

            tests_scroller.text = multiLineString
            myDatabase.close()
        }
```

How can I join a checkbox button created with the code below to each string line in the TextView?

```
let checkButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(300, 500, 20, 20))
checkButton.tintColor=UIColor.blackColor()
checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox-checked.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
checkButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(checkButton)
```

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Well, yes, it's checked but this is all testing at this stage.  Will turning it off help with this?

Comment: Nope you don't have to turn it off!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create UITableView instead of UITextView. Then create cell prototype with UILabel (or UITextView if editing is necessary) and checkbox.

[image]

Then use your array of strings as datasource

Comment: Thanks, sounds OK , but I want the list of strings to be scrollable, would this work for your solution?

Comment: Also, I get the following errors: "The tests_label outlet from the ViewController to the UILabel is invalid.  Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."  Same for a button I added to the cell to the left of the label...

Comment: Well, UITableView is scrollable. You cannot create outlets to controller from tableview unless it's static. You should take a look how to create dynamic tables.